# Parallax Background revealing the edge of the image and content going behind it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I've just started looking at creating a parallax style page where the elements follow the mouse.

I have seen a few tutorials and so far i have the effect working, however the image that is the back ground has gone super sized.

**Normal Zoom:** [image]

As you can see the edge of the image is revealed and also the content behind it which shouldn't be there (mentioned further down)

**it should look like this:** [image]

and the Main Text image should be in the center.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var strength1 = 50;
  var strength2 = 100;
  var strength3 = 200;
  $("html").mousemove(function(e) {
    var pageX = e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2);
    var pageY = e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2);
    var newvalueX = 1 * pageX * -1;
    var newvalueY = 1 * pageY * -1;
    $('.background').css("background-position", (strength1 / $(window).width() * pageX * -1) + "px " + (strength1 / $(window).height() * pageY * -1) + "px");
    $('.middleground').css("background-position", (strength2 / $(window).width() * pageX * -1) + "px " + (strength2 / $(window).height() * pageY * -1) + "px");
    $('.foreground').css("background-position", (strength3 / $(window).width() * pageX * -1) + "px " + (strength3 / $(window).height() * pageY * -1) + "px");
  });
});
```

```css
.background {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  background: url('pictures/switzerland.jpg') no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.middleground {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  background: url('pictures/ExploreOurPlanet.png') no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.foreground {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  background: url('http://placehold.it/350x350&text=Foreground');
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.content {
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background"></div>

<div class="middleground-container">
  <div class="middleground"></div>
</div>

<div class="foreground">
  <div>Test text</div>
</div>

<div class="content">Cras nec massa non ex congue hendrerit eget nec lorem. Proin vestibulum ligula sit amet sapien pulvinar tincidunt. Suspendisse potenti. Nam dui velit, porttitor quis convallis eget, fringilla sit amet massa. Donec consectetur fringilla pharetra. Nam pellentesque
  odio arcu, at lacinia libero mollis a. Mauris quis blandit purus, id porttitor enim. Praesent finibus, nisl vitae porta consectetur, purus mauris eleifend odio, sed dignissim libero lorem in magna. Quisque lobortis enim et velit imperdiet, lacinia malesuada
  tortor facilisis.</div>

<script src="scripts.js"></script>
```

And as mentioned before i have some dummy content written out however its appearing behind the image, in the CSS i have .content with a z-index of 4 but its not overlaying on top.

How do i make the image not so zoomed in but slightly stretched so when i move the mouse i don't see the edges?

What is the best way to make the content currently beneath the image down from the "Explore The Planet" text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cover the background images to the viewport by setting:
Background-size: cover;
Background-position: 50% 50%;

To each images and lower z-index for the content like 0 or -1 in the CSS. And in the Mouseover the background position will change based on your JS

And if you don't the edges want to see,
Use transform: scale(x); above 1 to go over the image above the viewport but keep the aspect ratio